# Is client side login for Facebook supported in Azure mobile app?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I would like to ask about an Authentication with Azure mobile app.

As I checked the document, Azure mobile service supports client side login for Facebook

Client-directed login operation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx

Using the Facebook iOS SDK for logging in to Azure Mobile Services
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2014/02/05/using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-for-logging-in-to-azure-mobile-services/

However, I cannot find any documents about Azure mobile app.
Is client side login for Facebook be supported even in Azure mobile app?
If it is supported, is implementation same as the document "Using the Facebook iOS SDK for logging in to Azure Mobile Services" avove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Mobile *App* is newly rearranged-and-rebadged for Azure Mobile *Service*. You can think them as version 1 and version 2 of the same project (Azure also provides one-click migration and its [detailed information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/)). Therefore, almost all documents and libraries for Azure Mobile *Service* are valid for Azure Mobile *App*.

For Facebook Login settings, you have to set **App Id** and **App Secret** values which obtain from Facebook Developer dashboard. The values of them can be set at Azure Mobile App Settings menu. please check out [Azure official document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-facebook-authentication/) **Authentication** section.